# systemd.network: define system-wide pool of unused ranges

Tags: networking, systemd

systemd.network(5) can be configured to automatically allocate an unsed address range by setting `Address=0.0.0.0/XY` and `Address=[::]/XY`. This is used in `80-container-ve.network` to automatically assign IP address ranges to the veth interfaces of containers.

While systemd avoids using already allocated address ranges, I haven't figured out how to limit the pool of available address ranges. In my use case I would like to only use address ranges from `10.10.0.0/16` for containers without having to supply a `.network` file for each container for static IP assignment.

As indicated in the manpage assigning `Address=10.10.0.0/16` doesn't have the desired effect but treats the address as static and assigns it to the interface (which is of course invalid).

Is there a way to limit the initial set of available address ranges (potentially system-wide)?